# Querying Many to Many with Conditions

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a gorm many2many model like this:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username    string  
    LikedBooks []Books `gorm:"many2many:user_liked_books;"`
}

type Book struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string 
    Likes       []User `gorm:"many2many:user_liked_books;"`
}
```

Where a `User` can like many `Book`s and a `Book` can have many `User`s that like it.
I now want to query for Books that have been liked, and return the top 50 liked books.
How can I achieve that using gorm? I dont understand how to query with conditions on book.liked = true, sorted by liked count, limited by 50.
I couldnt find an example like that in the docs or on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done in the same way you would construct a SQL query for the request you described, just using the gorm functions. It could look something like this:

```
var books []Book
tx := db.Table("books").
      Joins("INNER JOIN user_liked_books ulb ON ulb.book_id = books.id").
      Select("books.id, books.name, count(ulb.user_id) as likes_count").
      Group("books.id, books.name").
      Order("likes_count desc").
      Limit(50).
      Find(&books)
```

If you would also want to load the `Likes` field, try adding `.Preload("Likes")` to the construct above.

Comment: this worked right away @emin-laletovic youre a legend!